# c++ loop initializer and counters

Tags: c++, loops

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int score;
int numTests;
int total = 0; //why total has to be set to 0
double average;

cout << "How many tests: ";
cin >> numTests;

int s = 1;  
while (s <= numTests)  
{
cout << "Enter score # " << s << ": "; // why put the s there ???
cin >> score;
total += score; 
s++;    //why update the counter 
}
cout << "total" << total << endl;
average = (double)total / numTests;
cout << "Average" << average << endl; 
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

1.My question is that why does the integer total has to be put as value 0? (int total = 0)

2.on the line that I enter the score number why do I have to input the counter s on it? (cout << "Enter score # " << s <<)

3.and why do I have the update the counter (s++)?

Comment: Why do you develop using C++ before to study it? Your questions are very basic ones, some of them even in terms of programming.

Comment: question  1. In c++  and c when you defined a variable the default of value is anything from memory and its not null or 0   question  2. Cout<<  is for print data and when you write cout<<s; its shows values of s in your screen  question  3. s++ mean s=s+1; and this is for the loop end while (s <= numTests)

Comment: @skypjack Because someone will come and answer. No need to learn anything anymore.

Comment: @nik Why are you answering the "question" in comments?

Comment: sorry for it i answered its too

Comment: You most likely want a text book to read up on basic programming with c++. The answer present should give the information you ask for, so I will not add to these.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1. in c++ and c when you defined a variable the default of value is anything from memory and its not null or 0

Question 2. cout<< is for print data and when you write cout<

Question 3. s++ mean s=s+1; and this is for the loop end while (s <= numTests)

Comment: I can assume that you mean "for built in types such as int or double the default of value is anything from memory and its not null or 0". This is not the case for default constructed user defined classes (such as std::string, std::vector, myns::Orc).

Comment: That's right, for string is not null or empty and for any variable that defined in c and c++,good luck

Answer (score 0):

1. Before you start counting the scores from the tests, naturally the total number is 0.
2. You put the counter s to indicate which score should be entered, i.e. "score 1", "score 2", etc... It is there for clarification of the user. Imagine you are on the other side and want to see your average from 20 tests, but each time it just shows: "Enter score:" - first, you will not be sure it works, second, at some point you might become distracted and forget how many scores you have entered. So this shows you exactly where you are at.
3. `s++` means each time the counter increases with 1. So, when it reaches the number of tests, the loop will not continue. The counter is used as a condition for the while loop - so that the cycle will stop and not go inifinitely.